# Can't read XML string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Ajax call returning an XML string, but I can't access the result:

```
function testLimitePanier() {
    var reponse = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlsite + 'limite-panier.php',
        success: function(xml){
            console.log(xml);
            reponse['result'] = $('result', xml).text();
            reponse['message'] = $('message', xml).text();
        }
    });
    console.log(reponse);
    return reponse;
}
```

The XML log returns fine

```
<result><![CDATA[KO]]></result>
<message><![CDATA[some text]]></message>
```

But response is empty. I think I have issues with jQuery; how can I do the same thing in plain Javascript? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your response is empty because `xml` is a string, not an object of your decoded XML. You need to parse it.

Comment: what exactly do you try to achieve with `$('result', xml).text();`?

Comment: get the strings like "some text"

Answer (score 0):

When it is NOT wrapped in CDATA, it will be addressable:

```js
$(`<result><![CDATA[KO]]></result>
<message>Some text</message>`).each(function() { 
  console.log($(this).text()) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```